# Multiple ListViews and the Empty View

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

i have an Fragment which contains 2 ListViews. I try to set the EmptyView for each of them.
I tried to add them via XML using @id/android:empty and via Code, both times their get ignorend.

Anyone got it working with two ListViews and diffent Empty View ?

Answer (score 0):

It is working, you have to make sure that the `View` (for the empty state) is added to your layout, where the `ListView` is in.

Also, the `Adapter` for your `ListView` have to be `null` or `isEmpty()` must be true to display the empty view.

If you have still problems, post some code.

Comment: I did exactly this, its not working. both listview are  in an LinearLayout for themself with this textview which should act as empty view.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Leandros is on the right track, you need to make sure that each list is set up correctly.  It sounds like there might be a mismatch when you are defining `@id/android:empty` twice in the same xml.  You may need to give them unique ids, then hook them up them in the java.

Your xml might look something like this:

```
...
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/empty1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="List 1 is empty"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/empty2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="List 2 is empty"
        />
</LinearLayout>
...
```

Then in the fragment, you'll need to grab the views and attach them.

```
...
    ListView list1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
    View empty1 = findViewById(R.id.empty1);
    list1.setEmptyView(empty1);

    ListView list2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
    View empty2 = findViewById(R.id.empty2);
    list2.setEmptyView(empty2);
...
```

And if you really want a more complicated empty view, you could include another layout in your xml instead of the TextView.

```
...
    <include layout="@layout/empty" 
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        />
...
    <include layout="@layout/empty" 
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        />
...
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: How to set single empty view for multiple listview?